# How to avoid running the same loop multiple times?

Tags: c#, foreach, while-loop

Here is a big problem for me, because I can't get out of the loop. I got in `listDataReport.Count` only 1. But in the `foreach` from `beginDate` (example: 10/01/2010) to `endDate` (today), my file writes as times as date are going through from the beginning to the end.

What I want is only one write for the specific date in `listDataReport`

```
listDataReport = blReports.GetDataClientes(beginDate, endDate);

string dateSelected = string.Empty;    
while (beginDate < endDate)
{
    foreach (var item in listDataReport)
    {
        FileCreated.WriteLog(item.NmbrCliLeg + "|" + item.NmbCliProf + "|" + item.Namsur + "|" + item.Mail, false);
        dateSelected= item.DateUp;
    }
    beginDate = beginDate.AddDays(1);
}
log.WriteLog("Clients up date: " + dateSelected + ":" + listDataReport.Count);
```

It repeats as many days are between `beginDate`- `endDate`. And if i only get one Client on `listDataReport`that happens.

As you can see there's `FileCreated.WriteLog`creates a .txt which writes the data client here's the problem. In `log.WriteLog` which creates a .log file there's no problem in that. I'll show what I got from both files.

In log:

```
---***--- Execution Initiated: 27/03/2015 09:44:40 a.m.
27/03/2015 09:44:50 a.m. - Clients up date 03/19/2015: 1
===***=== Execution Ended: 03/27/2015 09:44:50 a.m.
```

But now in .txt file (Datefile03272015.txt) :

```
0123456789|7976967|NAME SURNAME|somemail@mail.com
0123456789|7976967|NAME SURNAME|somemail@mail.com
0123456789|7976967|NAME SURNAME|somemail@mail.com
0123456789|7976967|NAME SURNAME|somemail@mail.com
```

All the job runs each day and creates a .txt file each day. It doesn't matter the .log file here.

Comment: Just remove the `while` loop?

Comment: Or we didn't understand your need, in which case, you should edit your post, or removing the while loop will do the job as said Henrik

Comment: You are nesting your loops, so you are iterating the entire `listDataReport` list for each date - is this the intent?

Comment: @DStanley yes it's a loop for each day, but if I found one client added  one day for each day since select until today writes the same data, and I only write once, not anymore. The same if I found 499 clients in one day writes 499 times for each day. Do you understand?

Comment: @PabloCalderón We understand what the code does. We don't understand what you want it to do.

Comment: @Henrik sorry Hernrik here's an update.

Comment: I still think you can just remove the `while` loop entirely.

Comment: Can you maybe give an example when the code works fine? I'm also seeing two loops waiting for the same command. The foreach takes every date and the while loop restarts the foreach for the same amound of days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the keyword break to break out of a loop:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

```
int[] list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

foreach(int item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    if (item == 5)
        break;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Absolutely, I was completing it as you commented :-)